# Concatenating rows in a multi-column format in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Input** : Table *A*

```
company | name    | rank
---------------------------     
ABC     | Tom     | 1
ABC     | Harry   | 3
ABC     | Robert  | 2
DEF     | Chris   | 2
DEF     | Dwayne  | 1
```

**Output** : Table *B*

```
company |     names             | ranks
--------------------------------------------          
ABC     |  Tom, Harry, Robert   | 1,3,2
DEF     |  Chris, Dwayne        | 2,1
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to concatenate `name` and `rank` row-wise (based on `company`) in Table *A* in columns `names` and `ranks` in Table *B* such that for every row in Table *B*, the order of names in `names` corresponds to the order of ranks in `ranks`.

I'm using the T-SQL query below (Try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1a15/7/0)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, 
(SELECT name + ','
 FROM A as t2
 WHERE t2.company = t1.company
 ORDER BY rank
 FOR XML PATH('')) as names,
(SELECT CAST(rank AS VARCHAR) + ',' 
 FROM A as t2
 WHERE t2.company = t1.company
 ORDER BY rank
 FOR XML PATH('')
) as ranks
FROM A as t1;
```

Can this be optimized to use just one `SELECT` for `names` and `ranks` instead of two `SELECT` used above?

**EDIT** :

Using **Recursive CTE** (Try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1a15/35/0)):

```
WITH CTE (company, names, ranks, rank)
AS 
(
  SELECT company, CAST(name AS VARCHAR(8000)) names, CAST(rank AS VARCHAR(512)) ranks, rank
  FROM A
  WHERE rank = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.company, CAST(t1.names + ',' + t2.name AS VARCHAR (8000)), CAST(t1.ranks + ',' + CAST(t2.rank AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(512)), t2.rank
  FROM CTE as t1 INNER JOIN A as t2
  ON t1.company = t2.company AND t1.rank + 1 = t2.rank
), 
CTE2
AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY rank DESC) rn FROM CTE
) SELECT company, names, ranks FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: @JamesZ How would I ensure that a name in `names` corresponds to a rank in `ranks` in Table *B*?

Comment: In general, you want to avoid code like this in SQL - you're trying to store multiple values in a single cell. If you insist on handling this on the database level, take a look at `xml` columns, CLR functions or recursive common table expressions, for example. The `xml` solution would probably be preferred - it allows you to keep the original layout of the data instead of relying on ordering. You can then use that Xml in your presentation layer to build whatever you need.

Comment: Are you familiar with `.net` and `SQL CLR` functions? It's better to create a custom CLR aggregate function for such tasks. All you need can be found here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx